# SFTP error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (INTERMITTENT)

Tags: ssh, ssis, sftp

when we try to connect to a SFTP server we INTERMITTENTLY get the ff. error:

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I've been trying to search but i cannot find a similar case where this happens randomly - sometimes we can successfully connect and sometimes we encounter this error. We turned on the verbose log and this is part of what we read:

```
"2017-03-15 07:24:38.833 INFO SshSession(1)[8] SSH: Connecting to
 sftp.igxfer.com:22 using SshSession 3.0.5885.0.
2017-03-15 07:24:39.926 ERROR SshSession(1)[8] SSH: Rebex.Net.ProxySocketException: 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ---> 
Rebex.Net.ProxySocketException: No connection could be made because the target 
machine actively refused it.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 52.33.119.6:22
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)"
```

Any thoughts? TIA!

Comment: This probably applies: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ssh/2926/debugging-ssh-problems/18370/connection-refused#t=201703151332335395092

Comment: Thank you for your response @Kenster! What is weird about our case tho is that it only happens intermittently, whereas most of the cases I read on the site the problem is consistent and thus easier to troubleshoot.